# Formatting chart Y axis as mm:ss from int

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm curious if anyone has ever solved this problem. Basically, I'm storing an int value in seconds (in a SQL db) that I am then formatting as mm:ss on the report, this is easy as I can display as string and manipulate the integer using the below formula. However, on a line chart it obviously just plots the axis as an integer. The values typically bounce between 250 and 350. I need to be able to format these labels as mm:ss, does anyone have any ideas?
This is Crystal 2011.

```
NumberVar curr := CurrentFieldValue;
NumberVar mins := Truncate(curr / 60);
NumberVar secs := Remainder(curr, 60);
ToText(mins,0,"") & ":" & ToText(secs,"00")
```

Answer (score 0):

The TIME() function can be used to convert a NUMBER to a TIME which is then more easy to format and order within Crystal.

The number should be a value between zero and one.

i.e. TIME(field)  -or-  TIME(hh,mm,ss)

Many resources are available on the web that list the functions available. For example:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic660.html?lang=en